# How to calculate the product of frequencies of different elements of an array efficiently?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

We are given an array and I have to calculate the product of frequencies of numbers in a particular range of the array i,e. [L,R].

How to do it?

My approach:- Say, [1,2,2,2,45,45,4]. L=2 and R=6. Answer=3(frequency of 2)*2(frequency of 45)=6.

Just traverse the array(FROM L TO R) and put the frequencies of each number in a map; finally multiply all those values. Is there any better method to do this for multiple range queries online?

Do we require persistence ?

If the size of array is 'N' and number of queries is 'Q' . I want a much better time complexity than O(N*Q).

Comment: Do you mean "occurrences", not "frequency"? What does it mean to have a frequency of 6? "Do we require persistence?" I don't know, what do you mean by "persistence" here and ... do you?

Comment: Do elements in the array have lower upper bound?

Comment: To create a data structure that more or less directly looks up the values you could create N maps where N is the size of the initial collection, then for each position in the original collection you attach a map containing the number of occurrences *seen so far*. To find the map for [L,R] you would grab the map from L (or L-1) and the map from R and then do mR - mL to get the final map.

Comment: The *queries* could be similar to `O(Q*<unique numbers in collection>)`.

Comment: I want something like O(Q*logN), And please write a detailed answer and not just comments.

Comment: Here's a simple example using my approach: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6VinMf

Comment: That's not much better compared to O(N*Q)

Comment: O(Q*logN) is not possible in my opinion, I might be wrong. Think of it this way: How would you compute the frequencies of the numbers in the array without having a look at all the numbers at least once. That 'at least' once makes it O(N).

Comment: so what can be done to increase the efficiency at-least a bit ?

Comment: @VishnuDasu I think your reasoning is wrong. You will visit every element at least once in `O(n)` in preprocessing step. After that you can have `O(Q*log(n))` for executing queries, which results in total `O(n) + O(Q*log(n))`.

Comment: @Dejan Can you please propose an O(q*log(n)) algorithm, will I require persistence segment tree?

Comment: @Guhfggehlthon You didn't answer whether your elements in the arrays are lower-upper bounded integers. If they are not, you cannot use segment tree.

Comment: @Dejan The elements in the array can have a range of [1,10^9]

Comment: All elements in the array are positive integers .

Comment: @Dejan After pre-processing, how does answering queries make it `log(n)` for a single query? You will have to multiply all frequencies of each number, which would make it O(n) again. I am assuming by pre-processing you mean, pre-processing of maps.

Comment: I also do not think that a query can be processed in less than `O(n)`. Simply because for the query `(0, n/2)`,  we need to multiply `O(n)` numbers together (the frequencies), which cannot be done in less than `O(n)`.
Btw, if it happens that `Q` is much, much bigger than `n`, then a brutish preprocessing of all values, done in `O(n²)`, would allow to process queries in `O(1)`.